# How do I dynamically populate modal from PHP server side product data?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am retrieving some products from the database using PHP and MySQL. I am displaying these products in a carousel. When the user hovers, a "Show Quick Details" button will appear.

When the user clicks that button, a modal shows up displaying the product details.

**Example**:
[image: Product List]

---

Here is the modal when the user clicks.... (no, the products don't match right now, I am using a template the client gave me with example images ).

**User Clicks Button:**
[image: Modal]

My question is, how do I go about populating the modal with the correct product information? Do I have to create 10 modals dynamically in my PHP , or is there a better route? I am kinda stumped on how to approach this.

Here is the modal I am using, in case that is helpful for an answer:

```
  <!--====== Quick View Part Start ======-->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade " id="productQuickModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fal fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="product-quick-view-image mt-30">
                                <div class="quick-view-image">
                                    <div class="single-view-image">
                                        <img src="images/product-17.jpg" alt="product">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-view-image">
                                        <img src="images/product-18.jpg" alt="product">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-view-image">
                                        <img src="images/product-19.jpg" alt="product">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-view-image">
                                        <img src="images/product-20.jpg" alt="product">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-view-image">
                                        <img src="images/product-21.jpg" alt="product">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="quick-view-thumb">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single-thumb">
                                            <img src="images/product-17.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single-thumb">
                                            <img src="images/product-18.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single-thumb">
                                            <img src="images/product-19.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single-thumb">
                                            <img src="images/product-20.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single-thumb">
                                            <img src="images/product-21.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- Modal Quick View Image -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="product-quick-view-content mt-30">
                                <h3 class="product-title">Trans-Weight Hooded Wind and Water Resistant Shell</h3>
                                <p class="reference">Reference: demo_12</p>
                                <ul class="rating">
                                    <li class="rating-on"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                    <li class="rating-on"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                    <li class="rating-on"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                    <li class="rating-on"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                    <li class="rating-on"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="product-prices">
                                    <span class="sale-price"> €23.90</span>
                                    <span class="regular-price">€21.03</span>
                                    <span class="save">Save 12%</span>
                                </div>
                                <p class="product-description">Block out the haters with the fresh adidas® Originals Kaval Windbreaker Jacket. <br> Part of the Kaval Collection. <br> Regular fit is eased, but not sloppy, and perfect for any activity. <br> Plain-woven jacket specifically constructed for freedom of movement.</p>
                                <div class="product-size-color flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="product-size">
                                        <h5 class="title">Size</h5>
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="1">S</option>
                                            <option value="2">M</option>
                                            <option value="3">L</option>
                                            <option value="4">XL</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-color">
                                        <h5 class="title">Color</h5>
                                        <div class="color-input">
                                            <div class="single-color color-1">
                                                <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="color">
                                                <label for="radio-1"></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="single-color color-2">
                                                <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="color">
                                                <label for="radio-2"></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="single-color color-3">
                                                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="color">
                                                <label for="radio-3"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-quantity">
                                        <h5 class="title">Quantity</h5>
                                        <div class="quantity d-flex">
                                            <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub"><i class="fal fa-minus"></i></button>
                                            <input type="text" value="1" />
                                            <button type="button" id="add" class="add"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-add-cart">
                                    <button><i class="icon ion-bag"></i> Add to cart</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-wishlist-compare">
                                    <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-heart"></i> Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-repeat"></i> Add to compare</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-share d-flex">
                                    <p>Share</p>
                                    <ul class="social media-body">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- Modal Quick View Content -->
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- row -->
                </div> <!-- Modal Body -->
            </div> <!-- Modal content -->
        </div> <!-- Modal dialog -->
    </div> <!-- Modal -->
```

Any easier ways other than creating x number of modals?

Thank you

Comment: I am trying this solution I just thought of... <script>
$('.openBtn').on('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    $('.modal-body').load('includes/getModalContent.php',function(){
        $('#productQuickModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
</script>

where I include the item number and table name in the html attributes , then call a PHP page to return the modal body including the product info.  Not sure if this will work.

Comment: " Not sure if this will work"...better test it then, hadn't you. This is potentially a good approach, using AJAX makes sense, although you might want to send the server the correct item number so it can render the right data.

Comment: @ ADyson , ok this approach seems to work fine. I suppose I need to think about having the item number in an attribute might cause security issues, although this app only submits a quote, nothing financial. I will test this a little more, and then close this if it does indeed work as needs to. Thanks for looking.

Comment: " I need to think about having the item number in an attribute might cause security issues"...if it's just an ID, then how could it be a security issue? And ID is meant to universally identify an item. Your products are for sale, so they are publicly visible. You need to be able to identify them, so the ID must be present in the page. I'm struggling to see how that could cause any security problems - what are you envisaging exactly?

Comment: I was thinking the user could possibly alter the numbers to see items maybe not yet ready for public to see? But after giving this more thought, I do not see an issue here. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the user could do that. But if the items aren't ready, your application should have a property set on those items which says that, and your server should refuse to show them when those items are requested (by a non admin user). That's how you do security - by checking permissions and properties, rather than hiding IDs